# In AnyLogic version 8.7.6, variable to reference a stop line issue

Tags: variables, anylogic

In AnyLogic version 8.7.6, when trying to use a variable to reference a stop line and add it to the carMoveTo module, you encountered an error stating that it was not specified, and the variable was null during runtime, even though you set the variable to the name of the StopLine.

How to use variable to reference StopLine effectively

Comment: Share some screens and what you tried already, pls :) See https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow